# Writing an existing Excel file from db but with different headers

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb, export-to-excel

I have a problem that i can't solve even if i looked everywhere for a solution. I got an excel that have to be written from a table in my db, problem is that the headers in my db are named different than the headers in my excel file and I need to keep them like that. Another problem is that the index of the columns are also diffrent...It would be great if i could make a query for each column and write the result to the excel file by indicating the column's index, something like that:

```
Dim column1 As String = "SELECT  [columnName] from [tableName] "
```

and then

```
Sheets("SheetName").Columns("ColumnName").value = column1
```

obviously it doesn't work it's just to let you know my idea...

Comment: Why can't you use a different Excel file? One template for each of your requirement.

Comment: the template is correct but i need to keep headers with different names

Comment: Build your SQL query to match the order of the excel file and then fill in your result like `for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++){Sheets("SheetName").Columns(i).value = table.Columns[i].ColumnName }` and add another `for-loop` for the rows on the `table.Rows` to fill in the values

Comment: can't belive that i was being so blind...thank you so much @hiFI

Comment: @OmarIbrahim I will write the same thing I wrote above as an answer; Please tick it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your SQL query to match the order of the excel file and then fill in your result like

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
{
Sheets("SheetName").Columns(i).value = table.Columns[i].ColumnName 
}
```

and add another `for-loop` for the rows on the table.Rows to fill in the values